# Assembly function undefined reference to

Tags: c, assembly

Homework......
I have a C file below:

```
extern int count(char *string, char c);

int main(void)
{
  char string [] = "aabcabcabc";
  printf("The number of a's in the string is %d\n", count(string, 'a'));
  return 0;
}
```

This is given and I can't adjust.  My job is trying to write the assembly function in a count.s I am just trying to get things going as this is my first time writing assembly code.  I am supposed to compile it with make A=count

my assembly code is

```
count:


        movl $4, %eax
        ret
```

I am receiving an error on compilation that is

```
blade57(4)% make A=count
/groups/ulab/bin/i386-ld -N -Ttext 1000e0 -o count.lnx \
        /groups/ulab/pcdev/lib/startup0.opc /groups/ulab/pcdev/lib/startup.opc \
        countc.opc count.opc /groups/ulab/pcdev/lib/libc.a
countc.opc: In function `main':
/courses/cs341/s16/cheungr/pmanca/mp2/countc.c:12: undefined reference to `count'
make: *** [count.lnx] Error 1
```

Can someone please help me understand why this is and what can I do? I am assuming I am missing something in the count.s file but I have no idea what. 
As a FYI this is supposed to be i386 assembly

Comment: You must export the symbol from the assembler code, `.global count` should do the trick. (Note the dot at the start)

Comment: since you "noted" it.  What does the dot tell the assembler? Sorry first time doing assembly going through some growing pains

Comment: AFAIK it's just syntax saying "this is neither a label nor an instruction" in order for the assembler to treat it as "special" command.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I am still receiving the same error even when i added your line to the top of the file

Comment: Make sure you re-run the assembler. Your paste seems to indicate only linking.

Comment: Hm, I'm guessing that you're using gas assembler? Then it should be `.globl count`

Comment: yes gas.  I will try globl now

Comment: Same results.  Also Jester I am not sure how else to re-run the assembler other than edit the file to the new suggestions and run make A=count again. The makefile should re compile everything.

Comment: "assembler directives" is the correct name for this. Sorry, my explain-foo seems to lacking currently :D

Comment: Try `make clean`. If the makefile is written with at least a little bit of style then this should force the next run of `make A=count` to run the assembler.

Comment: ok I did and same result....

Comment: You should be able to see it, just as you see the `ld`invocation in the question. PS: `gas` accepts both `.global` and `.globl` and would produce an error itself if it didn't, not a linker error as you have.

Comment: Can you post the output of that make run? Or perhaps the makefile, given it's hopefully not too large.

Comment: so I just added .text to the top and did a make clean and a make A=count and i did not receive an error. I saw the .text somewhere in an example from class not sure what it does fully

Comment: `.text` switches to the usual section used for code. It is normally default.

Comment: good to know thanks,  Now for the fun part of actually writing the assembly function right but it appears to be at least compiling with my simple as possible version

Comment: The next question is how do I get to the variables that are passed in? They should be on the stack right and I should be able to pop them off into a register.  At least that is my understanding. I am getting an error when I add one pop line to the count.s  file

.text
.globl _count
_count:
        movl $0, %eax
        pop %ebx        
        ret